# Searching and reading files is slow in Shared and Mapped drives in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

Wrote a simple recursive program in c# which will search for".txt" files in Fixed, Mapped drives and read its contents and do some processing. Application works fine in my development PC which Windows 7 but when I run the same in Windows Server 2008 R2, it is taking lot of time and go idle after searching and reading few files.

- In C:, which is a local disk, the search and read worksfine
- In D:, which is a local disk but shared with simultaneous access to 16777216 users, the search and read goes idle after few files
- In E:, which is a mapped drive, the search and read goes idle after few files

  ```
  private void ReadDirectories(string targetDirectory)
  {
      try
      {
          var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(targetDirectory);
          foreach (string file in files)
          {
              if (file.EndsWith(".txt"))
              {
                  try
                  {
                      // Logic
                  }
                  catch (Exception ex)
                  {
                      //Exception handling
                  }

              }
          }

          var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(targetDirectory);
          foreach (string subDirectory in directories)
          {
              ReadDirectories(subDirectory);
          }
      }
      catch (UnauthorizedAccessException Uaex)
      {
        //Exception handling
      }
      catch(AccessViolationException Aex)
      {
        //Exception handling
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        //Exception handling
      }

  }
  ```

Comment: Can you clarify what "goes idle" means & that your logging all those exceptions?

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks. After searching few files application doesn't read anything further, and it doesn't encounter any exception also. There is a log viewer through which I can monitor which file is in progress? and are there any exceptions etc. After a certain file, the file read is not happening I am not seeing anything in my viewer.

Comment: processmonitor would tell you that, but simply adding some logging within the loop yourself is probably simpler.  Event Viewer should report exceptions but your handling any possible exception yourself - assuming "//Exception handling" is just a fake placeholder for code that actually does something.

Comment: @AlexK. Yes your assumption is correct, "//Exception Handling" is a fake placeholder, I have some code there which will do activity. As you mentioned I  will put some logging within loop and try to find out what is happening.

Comment: Thanks AlexK, You pointed me in the right direction. Logging helped to understand where the application was taking time. Thanks  again.